# Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean of type 'FileStoragePropertiesAedImages'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been on stack in several threads regarding this question although I still can not figure it out.

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aed.demo.fileupload.FileStorageServiceAedImages required a bean of type 'com.aed.demo.fileupload.FileStoragePropertiesAedImages' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.aed.demo.fileupload.FileStoragePropertiesAedImages' in your configuration.
```

I have created a `FileStorageService` and a `FileStorageProperties` files

### File Storage Properties

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
public class FileStorageProperties {
    private String uploadDir;

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }
}
```

### File Storage Service

```java
@Service
public class FileStorageService {

    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileStorageService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
        
        
        this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir())
                .toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
        }
    }

   ...
}
```

the above set up works like a charm and creates the directory `file.upload-dir=home/..` that it's defined in the `application.properties`

I tried duplicating these two configurations with another file upload directory in `application.properties`

### Second FileStorageProperties Class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aed")
public class FileStoragePropertiesAedImages {
    private String uploadDir;

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }
}
```

### Second FileStorageService

```java
@Service
public class FileStorageServiceAedImages {
    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileStorageServiceAedImages(FileStoragePropertiesAedImages fileStoragePropertiesAED) {
        this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStoragePropertiesAED.getUploadDir())
                .toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

and then the above error is thrown. I need to create 3 directories that I've defined like so in `application.properties`

```
file.upload-dir=home/..
mobile.upload-dir=mobile/..
aed.upload-dir=aed/..
```

prefixes are correct, why the second storage service can not be initialized and requires a bean type and the first one does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing is constructor autowiring at `FileStorageServiceAedImages` which requires bean of type `FileStoragePropertiesAedImages` but you have not defined bean of the type. You just added `@ ConfigurationProperties` to the `FileStorageProperties`. Adding `@Configuration` to `FileStorageProperties` will create the bean you required at `FileStoragePropertiesAedImages`.

Add `@Configuation` annotation to `FileStoragePropertiesAedImages` class should solve the problem.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aed")
@Configuation
public class FileStoragePropertiesAedImages {
```

Comment: indeed it did thank you, although why is it not required on the first one?

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperty` just for looking for properties and it is not enough to create bean. Spring looks for specific annotations like `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Bean`, `@Configuration`, `@Inject` etc to create bean.

Comment: On first one it is not required coz you are not autowiring it.. If you wish to autowire it or pass as constructor argument to some other bean you have to add `@Configuration` to it as well.

Comment: both have `@Autowired` annotation and the `@Configuration` is needed only in the second one

Comment: There must be a bean defined for `FileStorageProperties` somewhere otherwise it should not have worked.